# PHP IF statement not taking variable into account!

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a tabled view in a while loop, where a user can view information on books.

For example, book ISBN, book name, read status...

Basically, when the user sets their 'readstatus' to 'complete' I want that specific table row to become grey! The logic is very straight forward, however I can't get my IF statement to recognise this:

```
if ($readstatus == 'complete') {
                        echo '<tr class="completed">';
              }

                    else if  ($readstatus != 'complete') {
                        echo '<tr class="reading">';
              }
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, table content to change if the value of 'readstatus' = 'complete', if not, then output is the default

Comment: This is not answering the question, but you're equally well doing `if( a ) { ... } else { ... }`, without the test which should obviously return true.

Comment: Do you have your `if` sdtatement inside of the loop or, as it stated above, right under `$readstatus = $_GET['readstatus'];` ?

Comment: The `if` statement should at least enter one of the clauses; which one does it enter?

Comment: its right under the variable declaration (as stated above)

Comment: it enters the last clause being '!='

Comment: simply changed GET to $row, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `$_GET`? Does this information come from an HTML form or a URL etc... ?

I suspect you meant to change `$readstatus = $_GET['readstatus'];` to `$readstatus = $row['readstatus'];`.

`$_GET` is an aray of GET parameters which come from the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

`$row` is a row in your database, so if the information is in the database - which I suspect it is - you want to use `$row` instead of `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `$readstatus = $_GET['readstatus'];` to `$readstatus = $row['readstatus'];`

Answer (score 0):

The $_GET function relies on the value being contained in the query string of the URL, and it has nothing to do with the database.  I have a hunch you're trying to get the value from the database here and you're using the wrong function to do it.

Comment: `$_GET` isn't a function though ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['readstatus']` says the value is coming from the browser.
`$row['readstatus']` says the value is coming from the database.

You need to decide which should take precedence-- probably the $_GET['readstatus']` because it's what the user wants to change. If that's the case, you need to update your database with the new readstatus before you requery the db for the dataset.